# Why are real and complex numbers consider rings when irrationals aren't?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Irrational numbers are not closed under multiplication, then why are real and complex numbers considered rings? Aren't real and complex numbers supposed to have irrational numbers?

*Made the mistake of thinking if subsets were to be invalid, the higher sets would be invalid too. Thanks to @Zachary Selk for clarify it!

Comment: Irrationals are not closed under addition/multiplication.

Comment: You seem to be arguing that if $A$ is not a ring and $A\subset B$ then $B$ is not a ring. This is not correct.

Comment: Using the operations of the real numbers, the product of two irrationals isn't necessarily irrational, the sum of two irrationals isn't necessarily irrational, and there is no irrational additive identity, so the set of irrational numbers wildly fails the criteria for being a subring of $\mathbb R$.  Of course, you could make them into a ring with some weird product, but that isn't apparently what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3):

The irrationals are not closed under multiplication, but the reals and complex numbers are.  Why should the irrationals not being closed matter to whether the reals and complex numbers are rings?  $\{2\}$ is not closed under multiplication (or addition), but it is a subset of the integers, which form a ring.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, real numbers do indeed contain irrational numbers. However, the only thing irrationals can "escape to" are rationals, i.e. reals. So reals are a ring.

As a matter of fact, every nonzero ring contains a subset that is not a ring.

Comment: Yea, I made the mistake of thinking if a subset is invalid, the higher set would be too. Sort of a bad question on my part but thanks for the simple explanation. This answers my question best, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the irrationals are not closed under multiplication, e.g., $\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2 = 2$. And what would be the zero and unit elements?

However, what is interesting is that one can define a ring structure on the set ${\Bbb I}$ of irrational numbers by using (any) bijection $\phi:{\Bbb I}\rightarrow{\Bbb R}$.